# Is there an equivalent of a Solr RequestHandler in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, solr

I am currently assessing if we can move our Solr based backend to Elasticsearch.

However, something I can't seem to work out is if there is an equivalent capability of a custom request handler configure in Solr (as would be configured in the solrconfig.xml) in Elasticsearch.

For context, in our Solr configuration, we have a number of statically defined request handlers with a set of pre-configured facets, ranged facets, facet pivots. Something akin to the below, configured in solrconfig.xml:

```
<requestHandler name="/foo" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="fl">
           field1,
           field2
        </fl>
        <str name="facet.field">bar</str>
        <str name='facet.range'>range_facet</str>
        <str name='f.range_facet.facet.range.start'>0</str>
        <str name='f.range_facet.facet.range.end'>10</str>
        <str name='f.range_facet.facet.range.gap'>1</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

I could then GET a set of documents directly from that RequestHandler with something  like this `http://solr-host:8983/solr/collection-name/foo?q=*:*`
and Solr would return a document set with only the desired field and facets. Fundamentally, the application executing the query does not need to be aware of (or configured to) request all returned elements at the time of query.

My question is this - in Elasticsearch, is there an ability to configure an endpoint that would return only the desired aggregations and/or fields without having to post those to the API at the time of the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good article for this, https://sematext.com/blog/2014/04/29/parametrizing-queries-in-solr-and-elasticsearch/ . Elastic Search basically uses templates in place of handlers to make query calls associated with search .There are number of stored templates available for use too . See the documentation here [Template Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-template-query.html)